# WaitAny And SyncLock?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have some legacy code that I'm working with and I ran across something that doesn't make sense to me.

```
 WaitHandle.WaitAny(AutoResetEventArray, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, False)
            Do Until aListCount = 0
                SyncLock ALockingObject
                     'doing some stuff
                End SyncLock
            Loop
```

I'm far from an expert on Threading but my understanding is the WaitAny blocks the threads until receiving a set event so I'm wondering what's the purpose of the SyncLock.  Can someone explain either my misunderstanding of threading or a reason why the code would be structured this way?  FYI the size of the AutoResetEventArray is 1

Comment: The synclock is probably for some other thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WaitAny` call is waiting for any of the `WaitHandle`s within `AutoResetEventArray` to set. Once that happens, within the loop it locks on `ALockingObject`. There's nothing (within your code, anyway) to indicate a relationship between the handles in `AutoResetEventArray` and `ALockingObject`, so I would assume that there are other operations that use the resources protected by `ALockingObject`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Thanks to slaks also.  It is quite a bit of legacy code so I'll see if I can figure a relationship.  WaitAny(or any of the waits) only unblocks the thread it doesn't guarantee the execution of the code before another thread is unblocked and begins to execute...